# make url should only work within the requested device

Tags: php, android, ios, url

I have a very specific requirement, not sure this is possible or not.

I have a web page which should only accessible through a mobile app and also the url should only valid for that particular device. So that if someone share that link no one can access that page.

As an approach I used `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` just to check whether the request is coming from the mobile device.(Still I couldn't identify whether the request is coming from the mobile app or mobile browser only )

**Example:**

requesting url : `m.domain.com/page1/?device_id=xxxx`

so when I process this url I need verify the `device_id` is the same one as it is in the query string.

Please note that I am using `PHP` as the programming language.

Any kind of a lead should be highly appreciating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not solely depend on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` as it can easily be set by anyone making a request. I think sending some sort of a random string from the device should be enough. But if it is a highly sensitive page, you may want to use some sort of handshake mechanism where the device identifies itself on the server and uses one-time-only nonce or something to access the website. But under normal circumstances, your approach should be enough.